# Unable to make div arrow pointing to menu at the top right

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-shapes

I want to mark my div content with arrow pointing to the specific menu's button.
I have a menu on the top right, I want to point its div content with arrows. I created a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zaukt/1/). How can I show my arrow on the top right?

HTML

```
<p></p>
<span id="pointer"></div>
```

CSS

```
body {
    background:#ff004e;
    padding:40px
}
p {
    background:white;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width:250px;
    height:150px
}
span#pointer {
    border:solid 10px transparent;
    border-right-color:#fff;
    position:absolute;
    margin:0px 0 0 -20px;
}
```

Comment: You've tagged this question with jQuery, but your fiddle is using an old version of MooTools.

Comment: @Scottie there is no javascript necessary altogether. what is your problem with setting some `top` and `right` values @OP?

Comment: @Christoph Like facebook is using pointing to the status button, they shows a arrow pointing to the div from the button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/Zaukt/1165/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">

    <div id="pointer"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {background:#ff004e;padding:40px}

.container {
    background:white; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px; 
    width:250px; 
    height:150px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}

#pointer{
    border-bottom:solid 10px #FFF;
    border-left: solid 5px transparent;
    border-right: solid 5px transparent;
    position:absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    top: -10px;
    right: 20px;
}
```

Comment: modifying the border-left and right width, you can make the arrow wider

Comment: thanks, can you make it better, litle shadow in the arrow and to the div border

Answer (score 0):

Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/SSKwn/101/) what you're looking for?

HTML

```
<p></p>
<span id="pointer"></span>
```

CSS

```
body {
    background:#ff004e;
    padding:40px
}
p {
    background:white;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width:250px;
    height:150px
}
span#pointer {
    border:solid 10px transparent;
    border-right-color:#fff;
    position:absolute;
    left: 285px;
    top: 40px;
}
```

Comment: No, See this http://jsfiddle.net/Zaukt/1/, I have menu like "ask question" just like stack overflow on the top right, when users click on it then i need to show arrow on it i.e arrow on the top-right

Comment: Like facebook is using pointing to the status button, they shows a arrow pointing to the div from the button

Answer (score 0):

add to one div as like this

```
<div class="parent">
<p></p>
<span id="pointer"></div>

</div>
```

Define this  **css**

```
.parent{display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;position:relative;}
span#pointer{border:solid 10px transparent;border-right-color:#fff;position:absolute;margin:0;left:-20px;top:17px;}
```

**[Left-Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/SSKwn/106/)**

**[Right-Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/SSKwn/108/)**

Comment: Sorry, may be you are not clear with my question.  Say, I have menu like "ask question" just like stack overflow on the top right, when users click on it then i need to show arrow on it i.e arrow on the top-right

Comment: Sorry, your Right-Demo Is on the Right-height of the div, i want on the  Right-width of the div (top right)

Comment: Like facebook is using pointing to the status button, they shows a arrow pointing to the div from the button